# SharePoint Breadcrumb for two different list views of same list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, breadcrumb

Is the Breadcrumb for list views possible in SharePoint 2013?

If my structure was:

```
Home (site) > News(List view) > News Details(Detail View).
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could enable Breadcrumb navigation in SharePoint 2013 by customizing master page.(if you enabled publishing feature, you need edit .html file)

[image]

Check below threads for details.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/22da8c/sharepoint-server-2013-enable-breadcrumb-navigation-up-me/

http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.sg/2014/06/sharepoint-2013-restoring-2010-navigate.html